# Receiving GetStringUTFChars with JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am learning to use JNI with [this](http://www.worldcolleges.info/sites/default/files/jni.pdf) book. I am using it to communicate Java with C++.
If you look a the page 25 of this book you can see a piece of C code that "translated to" C++ should look like this:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Prompt.h"

using namespace std;

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_Prompt_getLine (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring prompt){
    char buf[128];
    const jbyte *str; 
    str = env->GetStringUTFChars(prompt, NULL);
    if(str == NULL){
        return NULL; /* OutOfMemoryError already thrown */
    }
    printf("%s", str);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(prompt, str);
    /* We assume here that the user does not type more than
     * 127 characters */
    scanf("%s",buf);
    return env->NewStringUTF(buf);
}
```

In my opinion, the declaration of str should be like this:

```
const char* str;
```

I just would like to understand if the book is wrong or there's some explanation for it. Because they do simmilar things later. My code works if I declare str as a char pointer but I would like to understand if I am doing something wrong.

Thanks a lot and sorry if I posted something wrong. It's my first message on this community.

EDIT:
If I compile with jbyte* the compiler gives the following error:

```
openjdk-amd64/include" -I"/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include/linux" -shared -o libPrompt.so Prompt.cpp -fPIC
Prompt.cpp: In function '_jstring* Java_Prompt_getLine(JNIEnv*, jobject, jstring)':
Prompt.cpp:12:43: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const jbyte* {aka const signed char*}' [-fpermissive]
Prompt.cpp:17:40: error: invalid conversion from 'const jbyte* {aka const signed char*}' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
In file included from Prompt.cpp:1:0:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include/jni.h:1619:10: error:   initializing argument 2 of 'void JNIEnv_::ReleaseStringUTFChars(jstring, const char*)' [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: Side note: The book is a very good reference; It's even recommended by the Oracle JNI documentation. However, you should realize that JNI's * UTF * functions use the _modified UTF-8 encoding_, and any C/C++ libraries you call probably won't recognize it. _Modified UTF-8_ is a crutch that works when the characters are restricted to U+00001 through U+0007F. (Do you have code that validates such a limitation on string values?) You can easily use the Java String and Encoding classes to convert strings to/from any of several standard character sets and encodings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jbyte` is the same as `signed char`, you can check it in jni.h:

```
#ifdef HAVE_INITTYPES_H
# include <inttypes.h>     /* C99 */
typedef int8_t jbyte;
...
#else
typedef signed char jbyte;
...
```

`GetStringUTFChars` is defined in jni.h as taking 3 arguments, it's strange you don't get an error for this line too !
The last argument is a `jboolean*` indicating if a copy has been made or not.

The return type of the function is defined as `const char*` on oracle website for Java 6 and 7, and it is also defined like that in Android NDK's jni.h file. The NDK adds a comment indicating :

> JNI spec says this returns `const jbyte*`, but that's inconsistent

So maybe an older spec said `const jbyte*` that's why your book uses this type, or the spec as been amended and your book is outdated.

Also, C allows the conversion from `char*` to `signed char*` (const or not), but not C++ that's why you get an error

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have added more information about compiling error.

Comment: @JayZeeGP I edited and found something else to say ;) That should answer your question

Answer (score 0):

It think there is a mistake in the book, if you look at the [JNI specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp17265), it is declared as

```
const char * GetStringUTFChars(JNIEnv *env, jstring string, jboolean *isCopy);
```

Comment: it's c++, no need to pass JNIEnv.